# Why would not the parent promise not catch the nested promise's rejection?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, es6-promise

Why would the nested rejected promise not be caught by the parent promise? But, If I do a "throw" inside the parent promise, it will get caught.

```
var parent = new Promise((res, rej) => {
    // this DOES NOT get caught by the parent. 
    Promise.reject("A plain reject");

    // this gets caught by the parent
    // throw new Error("Arbitrary  error");
});

parent.catch(err => {
    console.log("parent catches the error");
});
```

Update: I'm not trying to rewrite this where the parent catches the rejected promise. I just want to understand the "why"? Thanks!

Comment: I think you should just call reject("something"), not attach reject to the global Promise object.

Answer (score 2):

You are not rejecting the parent, you just created a new nested rejected promise and then immediately throw it away.

This is how you can rewrite this:

```
const parent = new Promise((res, rej) => {
    // nested reject
    Promise.reject("A plain reject").then(res, rej);
});
```

It's still a bad pattern. You should really try to avoid `new Promise` if you can. It's a bit hard to really tell you how to properly write it without seeing a more realistic example, because the above can be rewritten as:

```
const parent = Promise.reject("A plain reject");
```

**Edit** response to your follow-up:

Update: I'm not trying to rewrite this where the parent catches the rejected promise. I just want to understand the "why"? Thanks!

When you `throw` an exception, it's a language feature that stops the current function and bubbles up the exception until something in the call stack has a `catch`.

When you write a statement like:

```
Promise.reject('foo');
```

You:

1. Call the `reject()` function on the `Promise` object.
2. Discard the result.

Even though a (rejecting) promise gets created here, you're not doing anything with the result. It's the exact same as calling a function but then not doing anything with what was `returned` and wondering where the result went.

So your initial example:

```
var parent = new Promise((res, rej) => {
    // this DOES NOT get caught by the parent. 
    Promise.reject("A plain reject");

    // this gets caught by the parent
    // throw new Error("Arbitrary  error");
});
```

is effectively the same thing as:

```
var parent = new Promise((res, rej) => {
    // this DOES NOT get caught by the parent. 
    true;

});
```

or

```
var parent = new Promise((res, rej) => {
    // this DOES NOT get caught by the parent. 
    5;

});
```

or

```
var parent = new Promise((res, rej) => {
    // this DOES NOT get caught by the parent. 
    "hello".indexOf('h');

});
```

The line gets executed but it's 'meaningless' because it has no side-effects.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. The code I posted is for sandboxing/learning purposes to understand promises. I know there are different ways to write it. I just want to understand why the behavior.

Answer (score 1):

You have a reject function, `rej`, passed to the promise callback. You should use that to reject the promise rather than creating a new rejected Promise. This is what it is for:

```js
var parent = new Promise((res, rej) => {
    // nested reject
    rej("A plain reject");
});

parent.catch(err => {
    console.log("parent catches the error: ", err);
});
```

If for some reason you already have a rejected to promise, you can resolve it, which will fire the catch as well, although this seems like a strange situation to be in:

```js
var parent = new Promise((res, rej) => {
    // nested reject
    res(Promise.reject("A plain reject"));
});

parent.catch(err => {
    console.log("parent catches the error", err);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. The code I posted is for sandboxing/learning purposes to understand promises. I know there are different ways to write it. I just want to understand why the behavior.

Answer (score 0):

`Promise.reject("A plain reject")` returns a Promise that has its state rejected, that is just a regular Object, not an error that is thrown.

But you do nothing with the Promise that is returned from `Promise.reject("A plain reject")`. And because of that, there is no way that the Promise created by `new Promise((res, rej) => {})` can know what state that Promise has, (e.g. that it was rejected) and even if it would know the state, it would not know that it should do something with that Promise. You might want to do something else with the Promise.

On the other hand if you `throw` an error within `new Promise((res, rej) => {})`  then this happens immediately, stop the code execution, and the error handling is started. The Promise implicitly catches that error inside and its state is rejected.